# How to send messages on LAN running on Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, command-line, lan

In windows, we can send messages on same LAN using the `net send` command, but how to do this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send to one user, have a look at the `write` command. From the relevant man page:

> ```
>  The write utility allows you to communicate with other users, by copying
>  lines from your terminal to theirs.
>
>  When you run the write command, the user you are writing to gets a mes‐
>  sage of the form:
>
>        Message from yourname@yourhost on yourtty at hh:mm ...
>
>  Any further lines you enter will be copied to the specified user's termi‐
>  nal.  If the other user wants to reply, they must run write as well.
>
>  When you are done, type an end-of-file or interrupt character.  The other
>  user will see the message ‘EOF’ indicating that the conversation is over.
> ```

To send to multiple users, look at the `wall` command:

> ```
>  Wall displays the contents of file or, by default, its standard input, on
>  the terminals of all currently logged in users. The command will cut over
>  79 character long lines to new lines. Short lines are white space padded
>  to have 79 characters. The command will always put carriage return and
>  new line at the end of each line.
>
>  Only the super-user can write on the terminals of users who have chosen
>  to deny messages or are using a program which automatically denies mes‐
>  sages.
> ```

Also relevant is the `mesg` command:

> ```
>    Mesg  controls  the  access to your terminal by others.  It's typically
>    used to allow or disallow other users to write to  your  terminal  (see
>    write(1)).
> ```